# How to improve run on guitar

Tags: classical-guitar

I'm currently learning Capricho Arabe by Francisco Tarrega [(Youtube link to song)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXjSMrb8z1o).I am struggling with the run at the beginning of the piece (0:35):

[image]

and was wondering how I can speed it up and make it sound clear. 
P.S. It also has to be rest stroke.

Answer (score 2):

Using rest stroke (apoyando) this can be made very clear. As always, the way to approach a piece you find difficult is to start off slow.

- Find a speed at which you can comfortably play this
- Ensure you play it accurately
- Choose which fingers you are going to use (to me this feels like apoyando with i, m and a, but you may wish to play it differently)

Then gradually increase your speed. If you find you are tense or tiring, make a conscious effort to relax. You should also try altering the angle of your right hand, as some positions will be faster than others. Generally work towards finger movements at 90 degrees to the strings.

Apoyando should pluck the string then come to rest against the next string. To ensure clarity of sound, it is straightforward to only allow the chosen string to sound, with all others damped as needed.

Comment: Great concise but perfect answer.  Plus 1 of many more to come!

Comment: You may also want to consider a new right hand fingering. AMI scales are very intuitive to the hand, and can really increase your speed, although you may need to change some things in the left hand to optimize for this technique. Also I am curious to know why it needs to be played using rest stroke?

Answer (score -1):

Practice scales. And more scales. And when you've done that, practice more scales. What this does is gets you ready for passages such as this. Be sure to alternate when practicing!... `i m i m i m i m` or `m i m i m i m i`. You got this!